# Is there a way to access the iteration number in Postman REST Client?

Tags: postman

I'm using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for API testing. I'm running a large number of tests and I want to print the iteration number to the console on some of them. Is there a way to get the iteration number as an environment-like variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible now! You can access the `iteration` variable, in the same way you access other variables like `responseBody`.

Answer (score 23):

> According to [Postman API Reference](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference), *pm.info.iteration* - is the value of the current iteration being run.

Example:

```
console.log(pm.info.iteration);
```

Comment: Notice this was asked in 2015, and the answer seems to be changing regularly as Postman continues development. I do appreciate the effort trying to accumulate reputation on this site though. It can be frustrating as a new member. Good luck!

Comment: I think nowadays it is the best answer for this question

Comment: @toshiomagic I sometime answer posts after years too. To help other peoples who faced the same problem as me.

Comment: What's the correct thing to do in this situation? @Ellesmera was correct originally. But since Postman keeps changing things, should I mark this as the correct answer? Or do I just upvote and put a note in the quesiton?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is an internal way to get the iteration number but I believe you should be able to track this number through code yourself.  Here's a quick code snippet:

```
var value = environment.count;
value++;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("count", value);
```

If you put this in the pre-request editor or the test editor of a collection that you are sure will run once per iteration it will effectively track the iteration count.

Comment: I'm was going to do that but I stopped and thought "Surely this is a feature." I couldn't find it in the documentation so I figured I'd just ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the iteration number with

```
pm.info.iteration:Number
```

Is the value of the current iteration being run.

[Postman Sandbox API reference](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

I got there like this:

`const count = pm.info.iteration+1`

`console.log("======== LITERATION "+count+" ========");`